# How can make the Argon i.MX6UL board support touch screen?

Tags: android-things

I bought  an i.MX6UL development kit last week, sadly I did not notice that this board does not support display by default. How can I make it support touch screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need display with [SPI](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/spi.html) (or [I2C](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/i2c.html)) interface (for example like [this](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2-8-Inch-TFT-Touch-Shield_60335623171.html?spm=a2700.7724857.main07.211.3d48540hABwwi) or [that](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2-8-TFT-LCD-Display-Touch-Panel-SPI-Serial-240-320-ILI9341-5V-3-3V-STM32-/201950756171)) and custom Android Things [User-Space Driver](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/index.html) for that display. You can find examples of such drivers in this dirkvranckaert's [repo](https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/touchinputdisplaydriver).

Comment: For a display, specially if it's large, I suggest sticking with SPI, since it's significantly faster than I2C, and it'll be very noticeable.